# so im arranging these arguments from strongest to weakest, and am confused?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

1. Either reublocrats are uninformed, or democrans or independents are uninformed
2. it is not true that republocrats are uninformed
3. someone is uninformed
4. either republocrats are informed or they are not informed
5. republocrats are informed or they are not informed
6. either republocrats or democrans are uninformed
7. some people are both informed and uninformed
8. republocrats and democrans are uninformed
9. republocrats are uninformed

7,2,1,6,5,...  not sure if I am doing this correctly?

Comment: These are not arguments, these are statements.  It's unclear what you are to do with them.  A "stronger" statement is one that implies a "weaker" one, so perhaps you are to write down which statements imply which other statements.

Comment: Have you trie to symbolize them?  I agree with you that 7 is the strongest: it is a contradiction, and presumably 5 is a tautology: thus it is the weakest.

Comment: Instructions just said to arrange them from strongest to weakest

Comment: I think there has to be a transcription error somewhere- aren’t 4 and 5 identical?